# How can I save the parameters in neural networks at the end of every t-1 and use them to reinitialize train from that point?

Tags: matlab, initialization, neural-network

I am using Matlab and I try to train a neural network. Due to the big number of observations I need to reduce the computational time. Hence, I would like my network to save the parameters computed for time t-1 and use these as initial point for time t (instead of iterating say 1000 times for the solution, to iterate 6-10). The mocking code I prepared, without including the for loop, is the following, it works but without doing what I ask to do

```
clear;

x = randn(1,50);
y = x.^2;
HU = 2;

nets = trainnet(HU)
nets = train(nets,x,y)


net1 = configure(nets,x,y);
net1.IW = nets.IW;
net1.LW = nets.LW;
net1.b = nets.b;

net1 = trainnet(HU)
net1 = train(net1,x,y)



function net = trainnet(HU)

trainFcn = 'trainlm';
hiddenLayerSize = HU;
net = fitnet(hiddenLayerSize,trainFcn);

end
```

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the training options (like mini-batch training)? https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/trainingoptions.html
The use of mini-batch is typically for the case when there is a huge number of observations.

Comment: Hi Eskapp, thank you very much for your reply. I just did and it is not what I am looking for. Since, even if I amend some specifications of the training, and I benefit the computational time in the experiment, I will still need excessive computational time when my real data will be more volatile. In the example above I deliberately skipped the loop for time, in order to simplify it.

Comment: How big is the data?

Comment: One matrix of dimensions 4000*950. Each vector, namely 4000,1 , will be trained separately, under a rolling window. It takes around 9h to calculate this vector. Even if I use a cluster computer, 100 cores, I still need significant amount of time in order to calculate the whole sample. The only way is to do what I proposed in the initial question and find very close approximations of the solution. Instead of initializing the data for every time t, I could initialize the set from the solution of t-1 in order to find the the solution of t. On that way, I shoulf reduce the time by 100 times.